# How do I get records when Id's are in a text field of an object. These Id's are Ids of duplicate record and need to be eliminated using a flow

Tags: visual-workflow, query, formula-field, salesforce-id, fields

I am trying to extract IDs from a text field and trying to get records of the ID that are in the text field. Basically, the text field stores the IDs of duplicate records and only one of the records needs to be retained. I am using flow to get the records then I want to check which one to retain based on some criteria but I am stuck at the step where I need to be able to extract the IDs from the field and then get the records.

Example - field "Projects Duplicates" has the value "Project IDs: {a130Z00000JIdXoQAL, a133q00000RlADNAA3}"

I was able to remove the extra text and extract only the IDs. example - assignvar = "a130Z00000JIdXoQAL, a133q00000RlADNAA3". Then I used an assignment element to assign it to a variable. After that, I used the "Get Records" element and tried to assign the assignment element variable which stores the IDs but when I debug I am seeing this error.

This error occurred when the flow tried to look up records: Projects
WHERE ((Id = 'a130Z00000JIdXoQAL, a133q00000RlADNAA3')) ^ ERROR at Row:1:Column:53 invalid ID field: a130Z00000JIdXoQAL, a133q00000RlADNAA3. You can look up ExceptionCode values in the SOAP API Developer Guide.

Is there a way to use the text field that stores all the IDs and assign them individually to individual assignment elements and then pass it one by one?

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance for the help with this.

Answer (score 0):

Once you're as far as having the list of Ids, you need to massage it so that it reads:

```
Id IN ('a130Z00000JIdXoQAL','a133q00000RlADNAA3')
```

To get there, you can write something like:

```
String assignvar = 'a130Z00000JIdXoQAL, a133q00000RlADNAA3';
String[] idValues = assignvar.split(', ?'); // Put values into list
// And then join them together with quotes
String queryFilter = 'Id IN (\'' + String.join(idValues,'\',\'') + '\'';
```

Comment: I think the OP wants to do this entirely in Flow and with no Apex.